# perl array colon in key name

Tags: arrays, perl, namespaces

I have a sitemap we are trying to read in perl with XMLin. it have namespace in the XML, the colon, whats the proper way to reference this? We want to get to video:video->video:tag,etc.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'loc' => 'http://domain.net',
          'video:video' => {
                           'video:tag' => 'video tag',
                           'video:description' => 'description of video',
                           'video:thumbnail_loc' => 'http://thumblink',

                         }
        };
```

Our code so far, but we are stuck as you can see from the Dumper, and cant find the answer in Google.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

# create object
$xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin("./video_sitemap.xml");

# print output
foreach $e (@{$data->{url}})
{
    print Dumper($e);
    print $e->{video};
    print "###------------------------\n";
}
```

Thanks,
Levi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be able to just do this:

```
$e->{'video:video'}{'video:tag'}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, long day, swore we attempted that. LOL Night